# Using a derived class in c# out parameters

Tags: c#, derived-class, out

[Link why this isn't possible(MSDB Blogpost)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation/) (thanks @CodeCaster)

I have a method with an `out` parameter. The `out` parameter is a derived class `Derived`. Is it possible to store this out parameter in the base class `Base` of `Derived`?

I'm quite new to programming, so most likely I'm trying something that is just stupid or plain wrong... I'd really appreciate any help on why this is maybe stupid or how to do this better. (I want to keep the out parameter.)

Code Example (this doesn't compile, because the out parameter should be `Derived`:

```
void Main()
{
    Base b;
    foo(out b);
}

void foo(out Derived d)
{
    d = new Derived();
}
class Base { } 
class Derived : Base { }
```

~
[edit]

Thanks for all the replies. As @CodeCaster asked for a use case. Here is an more detailed explanation of what I am trying to do. The method foo has more than one out parameter, one of the out parameters causes problems.

```
Base base;
if(condition1)
{
    base = new OtherDerivedClass(/* ... */);
}
else if(condition2)
{
    base = foo(/* ... */);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

That's why I wanted the out parameter to

Comment: I do not unterstand what you want to do. How about something like:

    Derived foo()
    {
        return new Derived();
    }

If the Method should just manipulate the object you do not need to pass it as an out parameter. The changes made to the Object will be stored in the object itself.

You can not treat a Object of type "Base" as "Derived" if you change it to void foo(out Base b) it should work. You can not cast Base to Derived because Derived is more than Base.

Comment: _"I'm quite new to programming"_ - then don't bother with `ref` or `out` or inheritance yet, try to grasp the basics first?

Comment: well, have you tried executing `Main`? ;)

Comment: no its not possible. types must match. but it was really cool if it was possible :)

Comment: it would be possible other way round. In derived class you could use base class event if passed object is derived one, because casting to base class is always possible. What you could do is use generics where T would inherit from Base class, and then in foo return default(T). But it seem to be too complicated now.

Comment: Anyway see duplicate: _"C# requires that any ref parameters be of the exact type (no polymorphism) and the reference of that type must be assignable"_. If you can explain an actual use case for this scenario, some more sensible suggestions can be made.

Comment: @MadOX that's not possible either.yes casting to base class is always possible. but this one is rather syntactic problem

Comment: @CodeCaster & 'quite new to programming' -> I am new, however I do not want to use new classes to return more than one attribute from a method. I think it's better readable this way.

Comment: As for your edit, then introduce an intermediate variable of type `Derived` that you then assign to `base`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That's what I did, however, it felt wrong to add a seemingly useless variable. The blogpost helped to understand this.